# Dell Streak's screen cracked - what are my options?

Tags: screen, hardware

*I hope this question is being asked in the right place - it's not a question about the Android OS, but it is about Android hardware. Please move it if it's better off on SuperUser.*

I have just dropped my Dell Streak 5", and the screen has cracked.
[image: a cracked screen]

I have a couple questions:

1. I have heard amazing things about Gorilla Glass - the machine is under a year old, has anyone else managed to get the screen replaced under the warranty because Gorilla Glass is supposed to be so strong? Then again, it could be that the screen under the Gorilla Glass is cracked...
2. Is the screen actually replaceable or is this effectively a brick?

Comment: I edited out your third question since shopping recommendations are offtopic.  [The chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/android) might be a good place to ask, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this on the [Dell Forums](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/mobile-devices/f/3824/p/19350430/19765030.aspx):

> My Dell Streak Gorilla Glass broke today...i was coming back from eating dinner with the family and walking up the stairs the DELL STREAK fell out of my jacket pocket....and bam crash boom..it has  all types of cracks and glass pieces all over the place...
>
> SOLUTION....
>
> I immediately called dell customer care to see what my options where and the CSR...WAS JUST GREAT. She went out of her way to take care of all my issues and she did...before i knew it she had ask for my service tag on my Streak...and some personal info and the next thing you knew it was getting a email confirming that my NEW DELL STREAK was on the way....UPS TRACKING # i was amazed....how quick it was being resolved....THANK YOU DELL

You can also probably get replacement screens off ebay, and I am sure there are youtube video tutorials on how to replace the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume the Gorilla Glass is not broken, just the underlying LCD display, but I would definitely argue that it should have provided more protection if I were trying to get a warranty claim fulfilled.  I would also assume the screen is replaceable, most are; talk to your carrier though (not sure if they'll route you to Dell).

Comment: In our case it'll be Dell - we bought it directly from them unlocked.